# Use a pickerView on a outlet collection textfield

Tags: ios, swift3, textfield, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

My code bellow is a uitextfiled that uses a picker view to display a and b. All I want to do is have the is have the same picker view appear for all of the textfields using outlet collection. Textfield is the single textField and mutlipleTextifeld is the outlet collection the one I want to use. I I just want to replace textField with mutlipleTextifield.

```
       import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
let picker = UIPickerView()
let country = ["a","b"]

@IBOutlet var mutlipleTextifeld: [UITextField]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for textFieldObject in mutlipleTextifeld
    {
        textFieldObject.inputView = picker
    }}

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return country.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return country[row]
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   mutlipleTextifeld.text = country[row]

    self.view.endEditing(false)
}}
```

[image]

Comment: post screenshot of storyboard . Why you used cutler collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the `dataSource` and `Delegate` of the `pickerView` to `self` ie the `ViewController` class. As I see you haven't. So your `viewDidLoad()` would be somewhat like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    print (textFields.count)
    for textFieldObject in textFields
    {
        textFieldObject.inputView = picker
    }
}
```

And your `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` `delegate` would be like this:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    for textField in textFields {
        if textField.isEditing {
            textField.text = country[row]
        }
    }
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This is it! I have to wait 19 hours before awarding the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in your viewDidLoad method. that's it.!

```
let count : int = 0
for textField in mutlipleTextifeld {
     textField.inputView = picker
     textField.tag = count
     count +=1
}
```

Take a global variable in your controller with name `textFiledTag`

Whenever you tap on a textfield the following method will get called -

> textFieldDidBeginEditing

int this method write the following line

> textFieldTag = textField.tag

Now you can set text of picker view by getting the label with global tag value.

Hope this helps..!

Comment: how you will set text to textfield when value in a picker is selected

Comment: You can use tags for textfields.

Comment: I am updating my answer. please check

Comment: I am having a problem with let count : int = 0. Its coming back to me as a undeclared variable type.